# Jar files missing in tomcat8 startup

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat8, ojdbc

I am currently working on cloud migration activities.
We have installed a new “Apache Tomcat/8.0.43” in cloud server and transferred the war files from local to cloud.
while starting the tomcat server I’m getting below error :

WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/tomcat8/gdk_custom.jar] from classloader hierarchy
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/tomcat8/gdk_custom.jar (No such file or directory)

Similary, I am getting  FileNotFoundException for below jars :

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/tomcat8/orai18n-utility.jar (No such file or directory)
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/tomcat8/orai18n-collation.jar (No such file or directory)
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/tomcat8/orai18n-translation.jar (No such file or directory)
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/tomcat8/orai18n-net.jar (No such file or directory)
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/tomcat8/orai18n-servlet.jar (No such file or directory)
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/tomcat8/orai18n-lcsd.jar (No such file or directory)
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/tomcat8/orai18n-tools.jar (No such file or directory)
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

See Answer to question [Tomcat cannot find gdk_custom.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460750/tomcat-cannot-find-gdk-custom-jar-oracle-cannot-create-it#autocomment92228352)

To prevent Tomcat from looking for the not needed Jars, add the following line in /conf/context.xml:

```
<Context>
  ...
  <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: This doesn't get the warning away for me.

Comment: Grrr... I spent like two hours trying to understand why I suddenly got several not found classes warnings, and eventually my project wouldn't even run - when I saw this reply I instantly realized that prior to that I messed with my context.xml and that probably I had done some mistake. Of course, I opened a comment but closed it in the wrong place, affecting this scanManifest property. Beware anyone having this problem; it could be a typo in your context.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Generally JARs should be kept in tomcat's lib directory, rather you can `scanAllDirectories`.  Have a look at [JARScanner](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html) ( its about conf/context.xml ) and try all attributes of `JarScanner` with value `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used the 'find' command : find / -name "gdk_custom.jar" and found the jar nowhere in the server. Please help me to find these jars so that i can add them in tomcat lib directory