# Tomcat cannot find gdk_custom.jar, Oracle cannot create it?

Tags: oracle, tomcat

Starting Tomcat 8, I get a warning:

```
02-Aug-2017 11:14:21.363 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1]
org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan
Failed to scan 
[file:/C:/Users/543829657/HomeTomcat/tomcat/lib/gdk_custom.jar] from
classloader hierarchy java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Users\543829657\HomeTomcat\tomcat\lib\gdk_custom.jar 
(The system cannot find the file specified)
```

All answers that I have found, advice to create the `gdk_custom.jar` file by Oracle `ginstall`. I have limited the Google search to the last two years, and the answers are as [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch12custlocale.htm#NLSPG999):

```
java -classpath $ORACLE_HOME/jlib/orai18n.jar:$ORACLE_HOME/lib/xmlparserv2.jar ginstall -add <Name of NLT file>
```

But launching the line:

```
>java -classpath c:/Oracle/jlib/orai18n.jar:c:/Oracle/lib/xmlparserv2.jar ginstall -add lx2dddd.nlt
```

results in message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ginstall
```

I have looked into `orai18n.jar`. Really, there is not `ginstall` in it! `Ginstall` is in `orai18n-tools.jar`.

```
>java -classpath orai18n-tools.jar Ginstall -add lx2dddd.nlt

Usage: Ginstall [-dOutputDir] <NLT file> ...
-d: indicates the directory where the output file is written to
    do not specify 'd' for UDC, a zip file gdk_custom.zip will be
    written to the current directory
```

Ok, the text on Oracle docs is deprecated, it seems.

```
>java -classpath orai18n-tools.jar Ginstall -d. lx2dddd.nlt
```

Now it goes further, but again fails:

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:oracle/xml/parser/v2/DOMParser
    at oracle.i18n.util.builder.NLTParser.<init>(NLTParser.java:72)
    at oracle.i18n.util.builder.CharSetParser.<init>(CharSetParser.java:44)
    at oracle.i18n.util.builder.CharSetParser.getInstance(CharSetParser.java:64)
    at oracle.i18n.util.builder.CharDataTypeParser.<init>(CharDataTypeParser.java:123)
    at oracle.i18n.util.builder.CharConvBuilder.buildGLB(CharConvBuilder.java:95)
    at Ginstall.main(Ginstall.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xml.parser.v2.DOMParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Maybe, that parser was necessary? But

```
>java -cp orai18n-tools.jar;c:/Oracle/lib/xmlparserv2.jar Ginstall -d. lx2dddd.nlt
```

has the same result.

And no `gdk_custom.jar` (nor zip) is created....

What is interesting, according to http://www.findjar.com/jar/com.oracle/oc4j/11/jars/xmlparserv2.jar.html?all=true,  xmlparserv2.jar must contain the DOMParser class.

How can I get that `gdk_custom.jar`?

Oracle is 12.

Comment: See also answers to question [Jar files missing in tomcat8 startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796724/jar-files-missing-in-tomcat8-startup)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We needn't to create `gdk_custom.jar`.

All we need is to prevent Tomcat from looking for it. Since `Tomcat 8.0.38` it is scanning [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42329948/715269). We should turn the scan off. Thus you won't see many excessive warnings and the launch of server will go faster.

add the following line in `tomcat/conf/context.xml`:

```
<Context>
  ...
  <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: finally this can be also done through code (e.g. for embedded tomcat) according to answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370840/disable-scanmanifest-of-jar-scan-in-tomcat-embed-in-spring-boot